# Use Same Event Arugments For GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, indexing, gridview

When using a gridviews there are 4 commonly used event handlers:

- _SelectedIndexChanged which uses .SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text to get the selected row
- _RowEditing which uses gridiview.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex to set row to edit mode
- _RowUpdating which uses  e.RowIndex to retrieve the row index for which the Update button was clicked
- _RowCancelingEdit gridviewname.EditIndex = -1 to return the griview back to the original state

Is there a way you can use so you don't need to remember SelectedRow, EditIndex, RowIndex for all of these event handlers? I think this has something to do with the sender object but I couldn't find any examples

Answer (score 0):

and you left out the VERY common 5th one - row command.

There not really a way around this event model. For example, if you drop a button on a gridview (or better these days listview - I like listview better since you don't have to wrap each asp.net control inside of a template - you can just drag + drop controls into a list view - with gridview you need the messy template div.

So, in a lost of cases? I will skip all of the 4-5 events, and just code right past the whole mess.

Say I drop a asp.net button into that gridview/list view? Well, in place of say those 5 possible events and model to deal with? You "can" put in the attribute CommandName="select". Doing so will trigger both command row and index changed (row index will not have changed yet in command row event, but both events will fire). But command row does allow you to get the passed row anyway.

But, I often toss all above aside. I often don't want to mess with all those extra template and all those complex events - they can be hard to deal with.

So, I'll drop in a button. You can wire up a event in the markup like this:

```
 <asp:Button ID="pUploadFiles"  runat="server" cssclass="pUploadFiles"
                    Text='Upload Files' 
                     PortalComp      = '<%# Eval("PortalComp")%>'
                     ContactNameID   = '<%# Eval("ContactNameID")%>'
                     QuoteNum        = '<%# Eval("QuoteNum")%>'
                     ProjectHeaderID = '<%# Eval("ID")%>'
                     ContactGeneralID = '<%# Eval("ContactGeneralID")%>'

                    >
                </asp:Button>
```

So in above, I just toss in some extra attributes. And those columns DO NOT even have to be part of the grid - only the sql at databind() time.

So, passing PK values or whatever? I just include in the button.

Then in the click event, you can do this:

```
 dim btn    as Button
 btn = Sender
 With btn.Attributes
    Session("PortalComp") = .Item("PortalComp")
    Session("ContactID") = .Item("ContactNameID")
```

So, I just skip everything. And you can add a event stub to any button. While such buttons are dropped into that grid - you can't double click on the button to generate the event stub, but YOU CAN do this while editing mark-up like this:

[image]

In above, then intel-sense gives you a option to create a button event code stub even for the one button. I find a LOT of people missed this tip. (when you choose create new event - it seems if nothing occurred, but if  you now jump to code behind, you see the standard event button code stub was created and wired up for you.
As a result?

You just drop a button into that grid view/list view. You then code as if this was any old plane jane button click. And you can pass say the row index, or the PK row value. And as noted with a few custom attributes for that button, you can hold/have even columns that are not part of the gridview/listview. The expression to pass the row index is:

```
CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
```

As a result? I am not dealing with the potential 5 common events for that gv/lv, but only code out things like I would with any other simple button dropped on the form. And I can with custom attributes pass a PK row, or above Container.DataItemIndex gives me the row index. so now GridView1.items(rowix) can be used to pluck out the row anyway.

Now, after a bit of time, one will begin to see/know the difference between the 5 events. Some pass the row index (which then allows grabbing of any row). Some events don't or will  not have changed the row index event (row command). So, over a bit of time, one will come to see/know/figure out what event is best to use. Often I will set CommandArugment="Select". This triggers both row command and index changed. But i put my code in index changed, since the row pointer will have moved - I find that easier to use despite that I had/have/can use two events that trigger here (row command + index change).

But, as above shows? Often I just drop in a asp.net button, wire up a event code behind, and ignore the whole object + event model in that gv/lv. It often less code and less hassles to do so.